# SELECT FROM table WHERE column IS DEFAULT?

Tags: sql, postgresql, select

Is it possible to build a `SELECT` query that selects rows where a certain column matches the default value?

It doesn't need to be standard SQL it will be Ok with a PostgreSQL only solution.

Is there a way to avoid using `pg_catalog`s?

Comment: yes you can use default value from pg catalog in query

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention that I know that, just want a solution with a simpler query if possible.

Comment: no, DEFAULT to be used for DML, not for selects, so no escape to use catalog...

Comment: @VaoTsun is the answer that this is  not possible except with the solution that I already know, and that was posted as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know it is ugly :) but it is working example for text:

```
create table t2 (i int,v text default 'Vao');
create table t3 (v text);
insert into t3 select 'Vao';
insert into t3 select 'Vao1';
td=# with n as (
    select column_default from 
        information_schema.columns 
    where 
        table_name  = 't2' and 
        column_name = 'v'
) select * from t3 join n on n.column_default = $$'$$||t3.v||$$'::text$$;
  v  | column_default
-----+----------------
 Vao | 'Vao'::text
(1 row)
```

**Update with reference**
[from docs:](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/ddl-default.html)

> A column can be assigned a default value. When a new row is created and no values are specified for some of the columns, those columns will be filled with their respective default values. A **data manipulation command** can also request explicitly that a column be set to its default value, without having to know what that value is

Comment: yeah - same thinking - just used to joins as more fast comparison in most cases... but so far DEFAULT is only for DML - so no elegant solution for select there...

Comment: Thank you it's what I needed to know... And I think the planner would optimize it anyway, but I do like to be explicit about performance related things.

Answer (score -1):

you can find the solution here:

@ColsWhereCondition, @QUERY: I use them to make the query

@Value : your default value

@TableName: Table name

@TableSchema: Schema Name

and you can use it with your table or dynamic table
Code:

```
DECLARE @ColsWhereCondition as nvarchar(max) = '';
DECLARE @Value as nvarchar(max) = '';
DECLARE @QUERY as nvarchar(max) = '';
DECLARE @TableName as nvarchar(max) = 'TblMalls';
DECLARE @TableSchema as nvarchar(max) = '';
SELECT @ColsWhereCondition = STUFF((SELECT ' OR CAST(' + QUOTENAME(COLUMN_NAME) + ' AS nvarchar) = CAST(''' + @Value + ''' AS nvarchar)'
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = @TableName AND (@TableSchema = '' OR TABLE_SCHEMA = @TableSchema)
FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 3, '');

SET @QUERY = 'SELECT * from ' + @TableName + ' WHERE ' + ISNULL(@ColsWhereCondition, '1<>1');

SELECT @ColsWhereCondition 
SELECT @QUERY 

EXEC @QUERY
```

Comment: This is  not PostgreSQL and it's not standard either.